# Forcing a UIImageView to Remain in Front of an Active Animation

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview, layer

Language: Swift, IDE: Xcode for iOS development, Single View Application > View Controller...

I have 2 UIImage Views with identical images that I'm scroll-animating from left to right across the view in order to create a 'slowly-moving background' of sorts. I'd like to place other UI elements (Labels, other images, etc.) in the foreground of this repeating background animation, but find when I run the simulator the foreground image isn't seen...

Question: Is it possible to force other UI elements to stay in front of a repeating animation programmatically?

I'm not at my Mac so I can't share my code at the moment, but if you know a straight answer to the question and/or which method could best achieve this, I'm all ears!!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: glad i helped.Accept my answer...cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want z-index use:

```
     YourImageViewName.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Also you could play with bringToFront method on the parent view:

```
       self.view.bringSubviewToFront(YourImageViewName)
```

Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I'll give this a try this evening. Would I need to add any frameworks/library in order to access the z-order function? For some reason I thought it was only available when working with sprites (but I'm really new to programming, so what do I know haha ;)

Comment: you dont need to import anything....zPosition will push your imageView to forefront....try and let me know..thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Not sure if part of the problem was I had my forefront image view positioned at -= self.view.bounds though, so maybe that aligns it right side of view to left bounds? Lol. Anyway, changed that too so it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the z-ordering of the views.  Assuming you are adding all of your views then starting the animation call [bringSubViewToFront](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubview) on the view you are animating right before you start animating it.  If you are laying things out in interface builder the Z order is based on top = farthest and bottom = closest.  If you are adding view programmatically the newest view is always added in front.  You can change this with [insertSubview:at:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview) and the related methods.  Take a look at the documentation for [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview).

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll give it a go tonight. I'm laying things out in interface builder and the background view I had added first so technically it should be behind everything... They are also listed first in the browser/file tree. It looks right in interface builder, but the foremost views disappear in the simulator. I'm thinking it's more an issue with an animating view taking visual precedence. But I'll definitely try your programmatic suggestions and read through the documentation. Thanks!